# Combine multiple categories into one in Pandas

Tags: pandas, categories, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset with a column that contains categories. What I'd like to do is to combine these categories into new categories.

My dataset looks like follows (the categories column is a string column) and I have like 160 categories.

Below in my example, only four categories are shown.

```
Category  
ZA-01
ZA-01
ZA-01
ZA-01
XA-01
XA-01
XA-01
XA-01
YA-01
YA-01
YA-01
YA-01
WA-01
WA-01
WA-01
WA-01
```

What I would like to get is the following (with the original order of the rows in the dataframe being unchanged, this is very important)

```
Category     New_Category
ZA-01        A
ZA-01        A
ZA-01        A
ZA-01        A
XA-01        A
XA-01        A
XA-01        A
XA-01        A
YA-01        B
YA-01        B
YA-01        B
YA-01        B
WA-01        B
WA-01        B
WA-01        B
WA-01        B
```

The easiest way to do this is to use an if elif statement but if you have like 160 categories, this is a daunting task to do and it could go wrong easily.

What I would like Python to do is to take the unique categories with df.[['categories]].unique() which preserves the order of the categories in the dataframe and then say to Python: group category one (ZA-01) and two (XA-01) into a new one named A, then group category three (YA-01) and four (WA-01) into a new one named B etc.

Is there a way to this in Python without using an if elif statement?

---

### ------------------Edit-----------------------

What if I had

```
Group    Category  
A        ZA-01
A        ZA-01
A        ZA-01
A        ZA-01
A        XA-01
A        XA-01
A        XA-01
A        XA-01
A        ZZ-12      
A        ZX-11      
B        YA-01
B        YA-01
B        YA-01
B        YA-01
B        WA-01
B        WA-01
B        WA-01
B        WA-01
B        ZZ-01      
B        ZZ-99      
B        ZZ-99      
B        AA-01
```

And I wanted to combine categories of two within a group (so within A I want to combine groups of two categories and within B I want to combine two categories and so on). Again, I want to preserve the order of the rows in the original dataframe.

So I want to get

```
Group    Category   New_Category
A        ZA-01      1
A        ZA-01      1
A        ZA-01      1
A        ZA-01      1
A        XA-01      1
A        XA-01      1
A        XA-01      1
A        XA-01      1
A        ZZ-12      2
A        ZX-11      2   
B        YA-01      3
B        YA-01      3
B        YA-01      3
B        YA-01      3
B        WA-01      3
B        WA-01      3
B        WA-01      3
B        WA-01      3
B        ZZ-01      4
B        ZZ-99      4
B        ZZ-99      4
B        AA-01      5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For revised question**:

You don't need groupby. Just use `factorize` with tuple of `Group` and `Category`

```
df['New_Category']= (pd.factorize(list(zip(df.Group, df.Category)))[0] // 2) + 1

Out[272]:
   Group Category  New_Category
0      A    ZA-01             1
1      A    ZA-01             1
2      A    ZA-01             1
3      A    ZA-01             1
4      A    XA-01             1
5      A    XA-01             1
6      A    XA-01             1
7      A    XA-01             1
8      A    ZZ-12             2
9      A    ZX-11             2
10     B    YA-01             3
11     B    YA-01             3
12     B    YA-01             3
13     B    YA-01             3
14     B    WA-01             3
15     B    WA-01             3
16     B    WA-01             3
17     B    WA-01             3
18     B    ZZ-01             4
19     B    ZZ-99             4
20     B    ZZ-99             4
21     B    AA-01             5
```

---

**Original**:

Use `pd.factorize` and floor div 2

```
df['new_category'] = pd.factorize(df.Category)[0] // 2

Out[154]:
   Category  new_category
0     ZA-01             0
1     ZA-01             0
2     ZA-01             0
3     ZA-01             0
4     XA-01             0
5     XA-01             0
6     XA-01             0
7     XA-01             0
8     YA-01             1
9     YA-01             1
10    YA-01             1
11    YA-01             1
12    WA-01             1
13    WA-01             1
14    WA-01             1
15    WA-01             1
```

---

After having `new_category` above, if you want to map to your custom categories, just do these additional steps

```
cats = np.array(['A', 'B'])
df['new_category'] = cats[df['new_category']]

Out[163]:
   Category new_category
0     ZA-01            A
1     ZA-01            A
2     ZA-01            A
3     ZA-01            A
4     XA-01            A
5     XA-01            A
6     XA-01            A
7     XA-01            A
8     YA-01            B
9     YA-01            B
10    YA-01            B
11    YA-01            B
12    WA-01            B
13    WA-01            B
14    WA-01            B
15    WA-01            B
```

---

Add @piRSquare method of create alphabet categories

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

letters = [*ascii_uppercase]
leading = [''] + letters
cats = np.array([*map(''.join, product(*[leading] * 3, letters))])
```

Or

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import product
cats = np.array([*map(''.join, product(['', *ascii_uppercase], ascii_uppercase))])
cats[df.Category.factorize()[0] // 2]

Out[13]:
array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
       'B', 'B', 'B'], dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: If I would have 159 categories (uneven amount), would this also work?

Comment: @Eren: it works fine. Every 2-group will have the number increase 1. You need define the mapping between your categories and numbers.

Comment: Nice one. `df.Category.factorize()` works as well. The `chr` can be dangerous as there are 80 categories here.

Comment: I'd have done it exactly this way.  You can get letters like this `from string import ascii_uppercase; from itertools import product; cats = np.array([*map(''.join, product(['', *ascii_uppercase], ascii_uppercase))])` then use numpy slicing `cats[df.Category.factorize()[0] // 2]`

Comment: @piRSquared: It's great way of using `ascii_uppercase` and `product` to construct continuous alphabet categories :)

Comment: For arbitrary number of categories [gist](https://gist.github.com/pirsquared/d5376204d1b39609428b9d71004e5c00)

Comment: Hi would you know how to make groups within a groupby series, I have updated my question, because next to your solution, I also need the edited solution in the question. My datasets are not consistent. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Eren: is there only 2 categories in each group of `Group`. I.e `A` has 2 categories, `B` has 2 catogories?

Comment: No unfortunately not. One Group can have many categories (even and uneven). One group can have like 160 categories (serious).

Comment: If `A` has two categories then I want `New_Category` to be one. If `B` has three categories, I want `New_Category` to be 2 for two combined categories and 3 for the third `New_Category` in Group `B` since we're grouping categories within a group. I edited my question again to clarify what I mean with this comment.

Comment: So basically I want to do the exact same as first but now tell python to groupby(`Group`) and then to do the factorize `Category` within that group.

Comment: @Eren: You just need `tuple` and `factorize`. I updated the answer. Check my updated

Answer (score 4):

You can do as you said with `map`:

```
cats = df.Category.unique()

# define new categories
# replace np.arange(len(cats)) with your category names
# e.g ['A','B']
new_cats = np.repeat(np.arange(len(cats)), 2)[:len(cats)]

s = pd.Series(new_cats, index=cats)
df['New_Cat'] = df['Category'].map(s)
```

Output:

```
   Category  New_Cat
0     ZA-01        0
1     ZA-01        0
2     ZA-01        0
3     ZA-01        0
4     XA-01        0
5     XA-01        0
6     XA-01        0
7     XA-01        0
8     YA-01        1
9     YA-01        1
10    YA-01        1
11    YA-01        1
12    WA-01        1
13    WA-01        1
14    WA-01        1
15    WA-01        1
```

---

**Detail**: `s` is

```
ZA-01    0
XA-01    0
YA-01    1
WA-01    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: If I would have 159 categories (uneven amount), would your method also work?

Comment: Yes, the `[:len(cats)]` takes care of that.